# alter email address in DB to render it un-deliverable

Tags: email-address

I need to alter email addresses of users to render them undeliverable (not ever a real address), **however it needs to be reversible** so that the original is visible or at least retrievable (without storing it elsewhere).

For example `john@example.com -> NONAME_john@exampleNOTHING.com` might work as it can be changed back. 
 However, the problem is that I cannot KNOW that the above-resulting address is not a real email address. Maybe there is a real address out there called NONAME_john@exampleNOTHING.com.

The requirements are that the address needs to be valid (in terms of having '@' and '.com' etc) but won't send.

Maybe my requirements are a contradiction and hence not possible?  Does anyone know?

Comment: Replace all `.` with [DOT] or something? All DNS lookups would fail. If you really want it to have at least 1 tld, you could try adding another `@` to try and fool your validation.

Comment: Append an [.invalid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.invalid) extension?

Comment: @JimWright  but wont NONAME_john@exampleNOTHINGDOTcom be invalid as well as undeliverable?

Comment: @Storm  isnt that page referring to invalid domain names rather than invalid extensions.  So I cannot change the domain name completely.  Are you saying I can use john@example.com.invalid?

Comment: @RobMcFeely `.invalid` is a [Top-level Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain), just like `.com`, and yes I meant to append it to the email, that is why I called it an extension. You could then recover the original email by removing that extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements *are* kind of a contradiction. The only way to make an addres unworkable is to render it *practically* invalid.

Note that "invalid" can mean at least three things;

1. it doesn't parse as an e-mail address (e.g. replace @ by ⓐ)
2. the user name is invalid at that domain
3. the domain name is invalid

The point is that for 2 and 3 there is no easy way to know for sure if that is the case.

---

What you also could do is obfuscate the e-mail addres by applying a reversable transformation, like e.g. base64 encoding it. This falls under category 1 above.

For example in Python 3:

```
In [1]: import base64 

In [2]: base64.b64encode('john@example.com'.encode('utf-8')) 
Out[2]: b'am9obkBleGFtcGxlLmNvbQ=='

In [3]: base64.b64decode(b'am9obkBleGFtcGxlLmNvbQ==').decode('utf-8') 
Out[3]: 'john@example.com'
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this without storing any data anywhere else.  The DB here is just an example.  In reality, it is a third party system where I cannot store anything.  Only change this field

Comment: unfortunately encoding it will loose the '@' encoding its parts may be the only way as its HIGHLY unlikely that the resulting email will be a valid address.